# Wordpress query multiple conditions

Tags: php, wordpress

I've got this query to execute:

```
<?php query_posts(array('category__and'  => array( 9, 7 ) ), 'posts_per_page' => 4 ));?>
```

I need to match the array of two categories and limit posts per page.

It seems that the multiple query should be working ok according to [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters)  and the query worked just fine with one category before.

I don't know what might be the issue, I'm pretty new to WP. It's probably something very basic for an experienced WP coder.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

replace **category_*and*** with **category_in**

```
$args = array(  'category__in' => array(9,7), 'posts_per_page' => 4);

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Answer (score -2):

I found I have too many brackets, so nevermind.. cheers!